# Condicionales anidadas en SQL

Tags: mysql, condiciones, usecase

Requiero realizar una consulta que me permita calcular el número de días de un contrato tomando la fecha inicio y la fecha actual y, de acuerdo a ese número de días poner una condición.

realice la consulta para calcular los días de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT contratos.No_contrato, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, contratos.Fecha_inicio,(CURDATE()))) AS diasContratos FROM contratos;
```

Sobre ese calculo de días requiero hacer las condiciones, para ello utilice la sentencia `CASE WHEN` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT contratos.No_contrato, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, contratos.Fecha_inicio,(CURDATE()))) AS diasContratos FROM (
CASE
    WHEN (diasContratos<=10) THEN "diez días"
    WHEN (diasContratos>=20) THEN "veinte días"
    ELSE (diascontratos>=31) THEN "Mas de Treinta"
END
FROM contratos)
```

Se que tengo un error en la sintaxis de `CASE` pero no he encontrado la información adecuada que me ayude a resolverlo.

Agradezco su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: El `ELSE` no lleva condición, es `ELSE  "Mas de Treinta"`

Comment: ¿No sería "FROM (SELECT CASE..."? No suelo hacer SQL muy complicado, pero creo que necesitas siempre el SELECT y luego invocas la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo que puedes hacer todo en un solo select, algo así:

```
SELECT 
No_contrato,
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Fecha_inicio) diasContratos,
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Fecha_inicio) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN 'Diez dias' 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Fecha_inicio) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN 'Veinte dias'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Fecha_inicio) >= 30 THEN 'Treinta dias'
    ELSE 'Menor a diez'
END RANGO
FROM contratos;
```

Aclaro que yo coloque los rangos entre 10 y 19 con diez días porque sino de existir un valor entre ese rango aparecería nulo por no estar definido en el case ni en el else. Ojala te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias :) si me sirvio.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos :)